# Regular expression not supporting line skipping \n

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find the right regular expression for a number with a line skip at the end ( `\n` ) but every time it's not working.

My regular expression is `/^\d+(\n)$/`.

EDIT : The text area contains :

```
22\n
33
```

Here's my code ( I'm trying to validate what's in the textarea and it's only numbers going there with `\n` at the end of each lines ) :

```
function valideChamp()
{
  var rExp1 = /^\d+(\n)$/;
  var aChamps = document.querySelector("textarea").value;

  if (rExp1.test(aChamps.value)==true){
    alert("Valide") 
  }   
  else {   
    alert("Invalide")
    return false;   
  }   
}
```

Comment: `'123\n'.match(/^\d+(\n)$/)` works fine.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the .match, what does it do?

Comment: It matches a regex pattern in a string.

Comment: Well I'm not sure on how it works but it's not working on my side. I'm using only JS

Comment: You're going to have to add some more code or something, it's really unclear what isn't working.

Comment: Your regex works fine if you really have a new line character at the end.

Comment: Edit the question, don't add code to the comments.

Comment: I've just done that :)

Comment: Should work fine provided the testarea contains exactly numbers and 1 new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check for any line containing only a number on it, you can use:

```
/(^|\n)\d+(\r?\n)/
```

If you just want to check that there's only a number, and then a newline, and nothing else:

```
/^\d+(\r?\n)$/
```

(which is what you were checking for, but that's an odd input pattern.)

If you want to make sure textarea ONLY has lines that are numbers, it might be simpler to check that `string.replace(/[0-9\r\n]/g, '') == ''`.  This will confirm if it contains only numbers and newlines.

Comment: The first part works but there's something in the code I think and now it's the code the problem and not the regular expression. Thanks!

Comment: The other answer about the double `.value` is definitely right, I didn't notice that.

Comment: Yeah I removed that but still, now everything is valid, even if it shouldn't be haha

Comment: Are you sure you're even getting the /right/ textarea?  Maybe you should use a class or id, rather than only 'textarea'.

Comment: I found the mistake in my coding and now everything works. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Remove ".value"
from this line:
if (rExp1.test(aChamps.value)==true){

Comment: It's not really working now instead of everything being invalid, now everything is valid haha

Comment: You need to update your regexp as well according to Todd Christensen. See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n7xy3Ln4/

Answer (score 0):

You're using $ and \n together which is slightly redundant.  Try

```
/\d+$/gm
```

where g = global flag and m = multiline flag.  Note this will match multiple lines.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: It's not working :/ I'll edit with what I write in the textarea if it can help

Comment: If you're only looking for the "first" match drop the /g flag.

Comment: Here's a fiddle, "not working" isn't meaningful - sounds like your not communicating your requirement.

https://jsfiddle.net/n36n7n4L/1/